# Representative in $Dcoh(X)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves

I heard that any element in the derived category of coherent sheaves of a complex manifold $X$ can be "represented" by a complex of holomorphic vector bundles. If this is accurate where can I find a good treatment about the topic? I would prefer some complex geometric approach rather than a purely algebraic one.

Thanks

Comment: Which part of this is unclear? The fact that an element is represented by a complex, or that the entries of that complex are actual vector bundles?

Comment: Isn't this true by definition? The derived category of an abelian category $A$ is the localization of the category $Ch_+(A)$ at the quasi-isomorphisms.

Comment: @NoelLundström I believe the question is why a bounded complex of coherent sheaves is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of locally free sheaves.